# Show Attribute Google Maps

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am using Magento version 1.4.2.0 ..

I created an attribute field "*text area*", with WYSIWYG allowed .. Recalling that the WISIWIG allowed the option "*Allow HTML in frontend*" disappears ..

I put my Iframe powered by Google Maps, but in the HTML frontend appears in full ...

I am calling the atrribute like this:

```
    <? php echo $ this-> htmlEscape ($ _product-> getData ('google_maps'));?>
```

How do I see the map, and not the code?